# Client-side-prediction and Server-reconciliation with timing inputs

Tags: javascript, client-server, real-time, game-physics, prediction

I have a question about client-side-prediction and server-reconciliation.
This is well explained in the first interpretation of this guy :
[Client-side prediction & server reconciliation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29816250/client-side-prediction-server-reconciliation)

I did a good implementation in my game for simple moves :

Frame #1 :

1. Client **applies** an **input** and push it in a *selfInputs* array
2. It **updates** his state
3. It **renders** his state (**prediction**)

Frame #50 :

4. Client receives an old updated state from the server (from 100ms in the past). This state contains the **last processed input** by the server
5. It **updates** his state (**authoritative server**)
6. Client **removes** all the input processed by the server in the *selfInputs* array
7. Client **re-applies** all the input not yet processed by the server from the *selfInputs* array.

Now, I have a problem for inputs that need a **cooldown**. I want that the player can't '*move*' for 1 second when using a '*skill*'.

Let's take this example : keep 'moving' during 3 seconds then apply 'skill'. Reconciliation ends after 500ms

I tried :

1) use global var 'usingSkill = true' and 'lastSkill = new Date()' at step 1 (!usingSkill is a condition to move). This fails the reconciliation because it needs to re-apply the 'move' inputs.

2) use 'usingSkill = true' and 'lastSkill = new Date()' as members of the updated state at step 1. 'Move' reconciliation is done but the cooldown is re-applied -> 1.5 seconds of cooldown -> 'lastSkill = new Date()' can't be re-applied

A solution ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Have a variable `timeUntilAllowingMovement` (or something along those lines), each frame, take away the milliseconds passed from it, when it's `<= 0`, you can allow movement, and when it's `> 0`, don't allow movement.

Comment: Did it. When input 'skill' is pressed, the timer is activated. Problem is that the timer is 're-applied'  as I said